# Find max value in aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, having

i have the following Query

```
USE Movies;

SELECT
    c.CountryName
    ,d.DirectorName
    ,f.FilmRunTimeMinutes AS [TotalRunTime]
FROM
    tblFilm as f
    JOIN tblCountry as c on c.CountryID = f.FilmCountryID
    JOIN tblDirector as d on d.DirectorID = f.FilmDirectorID
ORDER BY
    DirectorName
```

which gives me the following result:

[image]

so far so good.

Then i grouped my result, to Sum up the TotalRunTime for each Director and Country:

```
SELECT
    c.CountryName
    ,d.DirectorName
    ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL, f.FilmRunTimeMinutes)) AS [TotalRunTime]
    ,COUNT(*)
FROM
    tblFilm as f
    JOIN tblCountry as c on c.CountryID = f.FilmCountryID
    JOIN tblDirector as d on d.DirectorID = f.FilmDirectorID
GROUP BY
    CountryName
    ,DirectorName
```

this gives me following result:

[image]

Now i want the actor with the highest Count(*) (the colum 'no column name') and i tried this:

```
SELECT
    c.CountryName
    ,d.DirectorName
    ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL, f.FilmRunTimeMinutes)) AS [TotalRunTime]
    ,COUNT(*)
FROM
    tblFilm as f
    JOIN tblCountry as c on c.CountryID = f.FilmCountryID
    JOIN tblDirector as d on d.DirectorID = f.FilmDirectorID
GROUP BY
    CountryName
    ,DirectorName
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = MAX(Count(*))
```

But it´s not working :(. Can you please explain me why it´s not working in detail and how i can get the row with the max(count(*))? In this example it should give me the row Japan | Akira usw.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `TOP (1)` clause :

```
SELECT TOP (1) c.CountryName, d.DirectorName,
       SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL, f.FilmRunTimeMinutes)) AS [TotalRunTime]
       COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tblFilm as f JOIN 
     tblCountry as c 
     on c.CountryID = f.FilmCountryID JOIN 
     tblDirector as d 
     on d.DirectorID = f.FilmDirectorID
GROUP BY CountryName, DirectorName
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

However, this might be fail if the `cnt` has ties if so, then use `RANK()` instead :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT c.CountryName, d.DirectorName,
             SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL, f.FilmRunTimeMinutes)) AS [TotalRunTime]
             COUNT(*) AS cnt,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS Seq
      FROM tblFilm as f JOIN 
           tblCountry as c 
           ON c.CountryID = f.FilmCountryID JOIN 
           tblDirector as d 
           ON d.DirectorID = f.FilmDirectorID
      GROUP BY CountryName, DirectorName
    ) t
WHERE seq = 1;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. But why it isn´t possible to filter with a where/having Max(Count(*))? I tried another example.
SELECT
   Filmname
FROM
   tblFilm
WHERE
  Max(FilmOscars) and it isn´t working too? I don´t get the idea why.

Comment: @Trace. . . Yes it is possible with `having` or `where`  clause but this is more efficient way to do instead.

Comment: @Trace. . . It will require another `subquery` which could hold `max(FilmOscars)`. So, this would have two `subquires`.